# Looking for the question with nice notation on linear mixed models

Tags: discussion, search

I recall seeing an answer to some question about linear mixed models where the answer showed an elegant notation for the model. Something like:

$$p(y|x,\gamma)=\mathcal{N}(\beta x+\gamma z,\sigma^2I),\quad \gamma\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_{\gamma}^2I)$$

I can't find it anymore, though. I saw it last year, but I can't remember whether it was from last year or earlier. I also thought it was @amoeba's, but it's not. I tried both Googling, and using the site search for [linear mixed model]. Can you help me find it?

Comment: How much nicer was it than what you wrote here?  :) Are you just looking for a reference answer for this quoted notation, or are you looking for a better notation?

Comment: @amoeba hey, thanks for the compliments :-) I'm (have been, actually) more of a user of LMMs than a learner, so I wasn't sure my notation was correct and thus yes, I was looking for a reference answer which would confirm this quoted notation. But I also seem to remember it was a nice answer overall, so I would have probably enjoyed reading it again during the weekend.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/304374 ?

Comment: If not, it might help to review https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer%20%5bmixed-model%5d%20mathcal (26 hits).

Comment: @amoeba adding `mathcal` to the search query was clever...I was halfway through your list but I got bored (weekend laziness :) and I decided to use the notation of Doug Bates from `lme4` vignette https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf which is very similar to mine, but it allows for correlations among random effects.

Comment: @DeltaIV: I almost always use the notation $...+Z\gamma+...$ when it comes to LME, I based this on the notation used in Faraway's in [Extending the Linear Model with R](http://www.maths.bath.ac.uk/~jjf23/ELM/index.html). While I view Bates` opinions on LMEMs almost as laws, I dislike the idea of using $b$ instead of $\gamma$. The reason is that in multivariate settings where we just want to change our vectors $\alpha$, $\beta$ to matrices $A$, $B$, using both $b$ and $\beta$ becomes cumbersome, $\gamma$ generalised to $\Gamma$ without any issues. (But Bates' notation can't ever be wrong so +1)

Comment: @usεr11852 ah, I just used $\gamma$ "unconsciously": I felt that using $b$ and $\beta$ in the same equation "didn't feel right", but I didn't realize about the implications for multivariate linear mixed models (probably because I never use them).